# Why deleting DOM element inside component template is not safe in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

Since **Angular** internally represents a component using a data structure commonly referred to as a View or a Component View [source](https://indepth.dev/posts/1134/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques#:%7E:text=Angular%20internally%20represents%20a%20component%20using%20a%20data%20structure%20commonly%20referred%20to%20as%20a%20View%20or%20a%20Component%20View) and change detection works on this data structure , what should i do in order to achieve something similar to :

`var el = document.getElementById('someSelector');`

`el.remove();`

is it possible to not use **View Container** technique? and if not what is the reason for such a restricted manipulation for DOM elements

Comment: you try to work directly with dom, and you will have errors. It's bad practice in any framework

Comment: @SlawaEremin , i know that is bad practice , how to to do something similar that is best practice , see the example in the question please.

Comment: @TheNone use *ngIf

Comment: @SanjayChoudhary what about doing it from code ? See the example

Comment: @TheNone, in the entry you "add/remove" an element using `this.viewContainer.clear();` and `this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl)` but you simple can use a variable and put `<div *ngIf="variable">..</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would encourage you to update the DOM using Angular's built-in structural directives, you could use the [**Renderer2**](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) class to achieve what you're after:

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
    <div #parent>
        <div #child></div>
    </div>
    <button (click)="removeElement()"></button>
  `
  ...
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  @ViewChild('parent') parentEl: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('child') childEl: ElementRef;

  constructor(private readonly _renderer: Renderer2) {}

  removeElement(): void {
    this._renderer.removeChild(this.parentEl.nativeElement, this.childEl.nativeElement);
  }
}
```